# getting error that a template that extends can not have body

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working on jobeet tutorial.
When I am running the project on localhost like this:

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/ens_job/
```

I am getting a error

```
A template that extends another one cannot have a body in EnslJobeetBundle:Job:index.html.twig at line 7.
```

What should I do in this case?

I am using the index.html.twig as follow:

```
<!-- src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/views/Job/index.html.twig -->
{% extends 'EnsJobeetBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/ensjobeet/css/jobs.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
{% endblock %}

<!-- the rest of the code -->
```

Comment: <!-- src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/views/Job/index.html.twig -->
{% extends 'EnsJobeetBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
 
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/ensjobeet/css/jobs.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
{% endblock %}
 
<!-- the rest of the code -->

Comment: @thecatontheflat files are on this link https://gist.github.com/3216535

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This error occurs when you have content out of `blocks` in child template.

You have to remove `<!-- src/Ensl/JobeetBundle/Resources/views/Job/index.html.twig -->` from your `index.html.twig`

Comment: yeah, the prom is solved. this thing is comment na, then why this problem is

Comment: Any content that is not Twig code must be inside a Twig block.

Comment: Or rather, any content that is not Twig code must be within a Twig context, such as a block. (stackoverflow wouldn’t let be edit my previous comment)

Comment: Thanks! That was it!

Answer (score 15):

Twig doesn't allow any html syntax if you are extending layout. This means that even the comment  tags in html is treated as content outside the defined blocks. If you want to retain the comments then you can just do it in twig comments like this:

```
{# src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/views/Job/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'EnsJobeetBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/ensjobeet/css/jobs.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
{% endblock %}
{# the rest of the code #}
```

Comment: This is also an answer that could be selected as apropriate