# Importing Twig File in Twig File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twig, slim

Does anybody know why I would get this error? I am trying to import my header file into one of my other twig files.

**Note:** It works fine if I remove the extends link.

```
Type: Twig_Error_Syntax
Message: A template that extends another one cannot have a body in "assessmentBuilder/FacultyControl.html.twig" at line 2.
File: /var/www/html/dev/portfolio/libraries/Twig/Parser.php
Line: 374
```

Any help? I read up on Twig documentation but it seems poorly written and I could not understand why this is happening.

```
{% extends "home_page_tabs.html.twig" %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Assessment for Portfolio</title>

    <!-- css imports -->
    <link href="/dev/editButton/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="/dev/editButton/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dev/editButton/css/style_assessment.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- js imports -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/dev/editButton/js/script2014.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- secondary header that appears underneath the tabs -->
    <div class="page-header fluid-container">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>My Classes</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="container"><p>&copy; ASAP Media Services 2014</p></div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="/dev/editButton/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extends` is not just another word for include. It does much more merging work, i.e. it takes a parent file and selectively replaces single blocks with blocks you define in the extending file (the one that contains `extends`).

So first define a base template with some blocks. Then derivate this base template with `extends`and overwrite the blocks.

Have a look at this example: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html

The error message says therefore that in the child template file is code outside the `block` directives. You'll find this explained here: [getting error that a template that extends can not have body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739463/getting-error-that-a-template-that-extends-can-not-have-body)

By the way, TWIG has also an `include` directive. It's here:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

I could imagine it's more suitable for what you are intending (?). With `include`, you can simply "chain" templates together.