# create new blocks in child template which are not defined in the base template in Symfony framework

Tags: php, templates, symfony-2.7

Is it possible to **create new blocks which are not defined in the base template in Symfony framework**. I tried to do that but it doesn't include those newly defined blocks to the base template when running.
I have to include those code in a separate block in child template because it gives this error otherwise.Thanks.

> A template that extends another one cannot have a body in
>   applicationStudentBundle:Default:StudentRequest.html.twig at line 95.

addstudent.html.twig

```
{% extends 'applicationMainBundle:Default:maintemplate.html.twig' %}


{% block midPanel %}
    //block defined in base template
{% endblock %}

{% block stylePanel %}
    //block which is not defined in base template
{% endblock %}
```

maintemplate.html.twig  `//here mainPanel block is defined but stylePanel block is not defined`

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/applicationmain/js/material.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/applicationmain/css/material.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/applicationmain/css/formStyle.css') }}">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <style>
        .demo-layout-transparent {
            background: url('http://www.getmdl.io/assets/demos/transparent.jpg') center / cover;
        }
        .demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
        .demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
            /* This background is dark, so we set text to white. Use 87% black instead if
               your background is light. */
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Uses a transparent header that draws on top of the layout's background -->
<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">

        {% block midPanel %}
            My cool posts
        {% endblock %}

     </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the first lines of the applicationStudentBundle:Default:StudentRequest.html.twig template and the one that you extend there.

Comment: extending the template is working fine. But the problem is I want to declare a new block which is not defined in base template because if I didn't create a block in child template then it gives the above error. So I just need to know the way of creating a new block in child template. That's why I didn't post the code. But if needed, I can post the code also.

Comment: Is this your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739463/getting-error-that-a-template-that-extends-can-not-have-body ?

Comment: thanks.But it is not this problem, that error occurs if there are codes out of  blocks in child template. That's why I want to create new block rather than having codes outside a block.But the problem is that block is not defined in base template.

Comment: In that case, you should post your templates, so that we can check it a find the problem.

Comment: I have posted my code and appreciate any kind of a suggestion.Thanks.

Comment: The error occurs on the template "applicationStudentBundle:Default:StudentRequest.html.twig" but you posted the template "addstudent.html.twig". Is it another one.

And I still don't see problems on the template that you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

twig permits something like this:

```
{# base.html.twig #}

    {% block body%}

    {% endblock%}

{# base.html.twig #}


{# child.html.twig #}

    {% extends 'base.html.twig'%}

     {% block body%}

         {% block hahahablock%}

         {% endblock%}

         {% block newblock%}

         {% endblock%}

    {% endblock%}

{# child.html.twig #}

{# another.html.twig #}

    {% extends 'child.html.twig'%}        

    {% block hahahablock%}

    {% endblock%}

    {% block newblock%}

    {% endblock%}

{# another.html.twig #}
```